# Acess value of previous query into new nested query laravel

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent

I'm trying to query a data using the value of the previous model, like: `MyModel->whereHas(MyModel.NestedModel.value > MyModel.value)`

Here is the code that I'm trying to do:

My problems is on `$q->where('quantity', '<', 'inventoryItems.minimum_to_shopping');`, I need a way to compare the current quantity with the quantity of previous scope.

```
$itemShould = InventoryItemMeta::with('inventoryItems', 'inventoryItems.lastItemValue', 'inventoryItems.inventory', 'inventoryItems.inventory.property')
            ->whereHas('inventoryItems', function ($q) {
                $q->where('should_shopping', true)
                ->whereHas('lastItemValue', function ($q){
                    $q->where('quantity', '<', 'inventoryItems.minimum_to_shopping');
                });
            })->get();
```

Comment: Please can you provide the error that comes with your code.

Comment: If I use '<' nothing comes, and if I use '>' all items come, it's seems like laravel is comparing using inventoryItems.minimum_to_shopping like string

Comment: please try `$q->whereColumn('quantity', '<', 'inventoryItems.minimum_to_shopping')`

Comment: You're the legend <3
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with the `whereColumn()` function, it is used to compare *two columns* instead that a *column against a value*, i.e:

```
$q->whereColumn('quantity', '<', 'minimum_to_shopping')
```

Comment: On my case I need to do just minimum_to_shopping, inventoryItems.minimum_to_shopping throws an error

Comment: This is weird, this query works, but the first item always is being ignored, if the query is valid or not the first item comes.
I set quantity < minimum and the first item comes with his quantity > minimum
Any ideas?

Comment: Please try this: instead of the final ->get() call, you can output your raw sql with ->toSql() so you can debug the query.

Comment: Seems right, also it works if I use inventory_items instead of inventoryItems, there's a way to check the query with the running values?

`select * from `inventory_item_metas`where exists(select * from `inventory_items`where `inventory_item_metas`.`id` = `inventory_items`.`inventory_item_meta_id`and `should_shopping` = ?and exists(select * from `inventory_item_values`where `inventory_items`.`id` = `inventory_item_values`.`inventory_item_id`and `quantity` <= `inventory_items.minimum_to_shopping`)) `

Comment: Install laravel/debugbar package, it has a useful query logger.

Comment: Thank you! The problem is I'm running this query agains "lastItemValue" which is a scope (scopeLastItemValue -> return $this->hasOne(InventoryItemValue::class)->latest();) but when the eloquent runs the query it runs agains inventory_item_values what makes the query works wrong.

There's a way to specify to run against my scope, not against the model?